# Rails unexpectedly routing to index after form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a "contributions" model. The create form has two submit actions: "Preview" and "Submit for Review". When the user clicks "Preview", I would like to collect the form data and then show a preview on that same page. Here's how I'm approaching that:

Form:

```
    <%= form_with(model: @contribution, local: true) do |form| %>
      <% if @contribution.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@contribution.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this contribution from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @contribution.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
              <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= form.url_field :link, placeholder: "Unsplash photo link", required: true %>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= submit_tag 'Preview', id: 'preview-button', name: 'preview_button' %>
        <%= submit_tag 'Submit for Review', id: 'submit-button' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Contributions controller:

```
  def create
    @contribution = Contribution.new(contribution_params)

    if params[:preview_button]
      /// do some stuff to collect data
      render action: "new"
    else

    ...
```

Routes:

```
  resources :contributions
  get "/contribute" => "contributions#new"
```

**Current Result**

The page refreshes and the data processed in the controller is available (yay!). However, the url changes from /contribute to /contributions. If the user happens to refresh the page, they run into an error because I don't have a contributions#index view.

**Desired Result**

The page refreshes, the data is available, but the url stays as /contribute.

Comment: please share form too.

Comment: Edited to include the full form

Comment: Try changing `render action: "new"` to `return render 'new'`

Comment: @BroiSatse no luck with that. It still seems to render the 'new' view, but the url is /contributions

Comment: @rcrusoe add this in your routes after resources :contributions `resolve("Contributions") { [:contributions] }`.

Comment: @Chandan unfortunately that didn't fix it either

Comment: This is because when Rails PUT requests (for new) are made to a Model table, the route the PUT is made to is `/models`. This is the default behavior for `resources :models`. This is not the best use case for render, it's more used for errors in form submission. You are really trying to redraw the page. Use Javascript or redirect to two different views based on the submit button pressed.

Comment: This achieves the correct url, but the variable that I would like to pass is not passed. Is there a way to redirect and pass data along without stuffing it in the URL?

Comment: Reading into this more, I'm realizing that I'm battling rails here and trying to make it do something it doesn't like to do. I'm going to find another approach to this. Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score -1):

This is because the endpoint for create action is `POST /contributions`. And "rendering" a different action does nothing to the url.

You need to redirect instead.

Replace

```rb
render action: 'new'
```

with

```rb
return redirect_to action: :new
```

Comment: This achieves the correct url, but the variable that I would like to pass is not passed. Is there a way to redirect and pass data along without stuffing it in the URL?

Answer (score -2):

I can think of 2 options:

### redirect_to + flash hash

You can redirect to `/contribute` but store the collected data in the Flash Hash:

```rb
flash[:collected_data] = something
redirect_to "/contribute"
```

You can store strings, arrays and hashed there, though I wouldn't abuse it.

Then you can do `@collected_data = flash[:collected_data]` in your `new` action to know if it comes from a previous POST request.

### Render 'new' and change the url after load

You can use some javascript after the page is loaded to push a new state like:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  history.pushState({}, 'Some title', '/contribute')
})
```

This will change your current path to `/contribute` without actually loading that url, so you keep the response from `POST /contributions` but the url changes so your refresh is safe.